# Преобразовать и ключ, и значение Map.Entry за один вызов stream().map()

Tags: java, map, java-8, java-stream, enum

У меня есть `Stream<Map.Entry<?, ?>>` и его нужно преобразовать в `Stream<Map.Entry<Material, Long>>`
(`Material` это *enum*)

Вот функции преобразования:

- ? -> Material:

```
entry -> Material.getMaterial(entry.getKey().toString())
```

- ? -> Long

```
entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Number ?
                                ((Number) entry.getValue()).longValue() : defaultTimeout
```

---

`Material.getMaterial(String)` представляет собой получение значения из `HashMap<String, Material>`, следовательно может возвращать `null`.  Так как далее я использую `EnumMap` - мне нужно отфильтровать `Entry`, содержащие не валидные строки.

(и еще, мне **не нужно** выбрасывать `IllegalArgumentException` если строка не валидна, нужно просто пропустить содержащий ее `Entry`, поэтому метод `Enum::valueOf` мне не подходит)

---

Сейчас я использую:

```
ImmutableMap<Material, Long> outMap = configuration.getMapList("path")
                .stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .filter(entry -> Material.getMaterial(entry.getKey().toString()) != null)
                .collect(Maps.toImmutableEnumMap(entry -> Material.getMaterial(entry.getKey().toString()),
                        entry -> entry.getValue() instanceof Number ?
                                ((Number) entry.getValue()).longValue() : defaultValue));
```

С одной стороны, все не очень плохо - строки не меняются => хеш не вычисляется повторно (он кэшируется классом *String*), **но** мне все еще не нравится лишний `HashMap::get`.

---

Могу ли я как то преобразовать и ключ, и значение `Entry` одним вызовом `Stream::map`, потом отфильтровать лишь по `Entry.getKey() != null` и собрать `Maps.toImmutableEnumMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue())`?

---

P.S. я использую Java 8, поэтому метод [Map::entry()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) мне недоступен

---

**UPDATE**

Я стал использовать `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` в своем коде (в методе `map` просто создаем новый `SimpleImmutableEntry` и в его конструктор уже передаем результаты методов преобразований). Словами получается не очень, это лучше увидеть:

```
ImmutableMap<Material, Long> outMap = configuration.getMapList("path")
                .stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
                        Material.getMaterial(entry.getKey().toString()),
                        entry.getValue() instanceof Number ?
                                ((Number) entry.getValue()).longValue() : defaultValue
                )).filter(entry -> entry.getKey() != null)
                .collect(Maps.toImmutableEnumMap(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue));
```

Будет ли это оптимальным решением (именно пересоздавание `Entry`), если в исходном `Stream` может быть до *463* значений?

Comment: получение данных из хеш таблицы по ключу работает за константное время. Выполнить эту операцию 10 раз или 10000 раз для современных процессоров нет почти никакой разницы. Потому если у вас на входе 500 элементов, то я бы больше заботился о читаемости кода, чем о его производительности.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за совет. Мне кажется, что оба варианта читаются неплохо для кода `Stream-API`. Что бы вы посоветовали использовать?

Comment: имхо, вложенные подзапросы усложняют чтение, потому я бы выбрал первый вариант. Он и попроще и покороче. Но в идеале, я бы вам рекомендовал приглпсить любого коллегу, кто работает над той же кодовой базой, и попросить его расказать, что каждый из вариантов делает. Там, где коллега поймет ваш код быстрее, тот вариант бы я и выбрал.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо большое! Первый вариант, как мне кажется, создает меньшую нагрузку на сборщик мусора (в этом не уверен) + то, что вы сказали, так что выберу его `:)`